# How to call method from other component inside render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting the below error:

```
TypeError:
_AuthenticationService__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.checkUserLoggedIn is not a function
```

When making this call.

```
import AuthenticationService from './AuthenticationService';
 render() {
    const isUserLoggedIn=AuthenticationService.checkUserLoggedIn();
    return (
      --html statements
    )
```

AuthenticationService:

```
class AuthenticationService extends Component {
  registerSuccessfullLogin(username,password){
    console.log("user regsitered")
    sessionStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser',username);
  }

  logout(){
    sessionStorage.removeItem('authenticatedUser');
  }

  checkUserLoggedIn(){
    let user=sessionStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser');
    if(user==null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
export default new AuthenticationService()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neRAm.png)

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Added import statement.

Comment: add more information like your ```AuthenticationService``` to question.

Comment: Is `AuthenticationService` another React component, or is it just some Javascript code? React components don't call functions/methods defined in other React Components. Can you update your question to include all relevant code? In other words, can you share `AuthenticationService` and how it's exported and imported for use in this React component, and show this React component?

Comment: @DrewReese  AuthenticationService is another class component . Please let me know if you need other detail

Comment: Add more informations about AuthenticationService.checkUserLoggedIn()

Comment: @AlwaniAnis Added code for AuthenticationService

Comment: Yeah, you can't do this in React. You will want to extract that function out into a utility if you want to use it in multiple components. Since it's just accessing session storage this should be a trivial change.

Answer (score 1):

`checkUserLoggedIn` isn't an exported function, it's a class method in your component. If you want to share that functionality between two components, extract it into a separate file or as a function outside of the component in the same file and import it like so, `import {checkUserLoggedIn} from './helpers'`

If you want to share it with a child, pass it in as a prop. You could also look into the HoC pattern to share common functionality as well.

### Edit

```
export function checkUserLoggedIn(){
    let user=sessionStorage.getItem('authenticatedUser');
    if(user==null){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

class AuthenticationService extends Component {
  registerSuccessfullLogin(username,password){
    console.log("user regsitered")
    sessionStorage.setItem('authenticatedUser',username);
  }

  logout(){
    sessionStorage.removeItem('authenticatedUser');
  }

}

// don't export an initialized component
export default AuthenticationService

// then change your import to
import AuthenticationService, { checkUserLoggedIn } from './AuthenticationService'
```

Comment: @Kumarrajesh That just pulls in the component. What you want to do is remove `checkUserLoggedIn` from the body of the component and declare it outside of the component body (or in another file). See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function static by adding the keyword 'static'